# How Can I implement this in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, model

I want to implement a feature where user can "add additional details" to his profile. Here he should be able to create the label for the detail and the actual details like:

```
Education : Degree
```

where Education is the label for the detail and Degree is the detail.

Apart from this, he should also have an option to decide whether this details should be made `visible` or `hidden`.

How can I implement this using a new model Profile with the association User has_one Profile.

If I just had Label and Text for the new details, I could have tried `hash`, but since I would also have to get the details from the user on whether the user wants the detail to be made hidden or visible, I might require an extra field to store that value (true or false).

I am really confused as to how I can get the whole thing implemented together.

Please suggest me how I can implement this and also how can I update the model each time a user creates a new detail without changing the `schema` of the db.

I am working on Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see your problem (or I don't get it), but:

Why don't you just create a has_many `AdditionalData` with `user_id:integer name:string content:string visible:boolean`?

So you can loop through `@user.additional_datas.visible` (assuming you defined a scope `scope :visible, where("visible = 1")`.

Added benefit: You could make this model polymorph and add additional information to other things you have in your app without the need to create an extra "information" table for every model you want to store these.

For validation, you could also add a `data_type` field and create validations according to the data type (needs to be an url, a phone number, just text, ...)

Comment: So according to you i need to create a model AdditionalData and give an association to user has many, and then each time user wants to creates a new detail, just create a new entry into the record 
?

Comment: So can I specify the user has many  relation while creating the model ?

Comment: User `has_many :additional_data` and AdditionalData `belongs_to :user` unless you're doing polymorphism. But yes, you can specify it.

Comment: has_many :additional_data alone will do ryt ? Or should i specify both ? And I believe associations will be added to the files after generating the model ryt !!

Comment: You are good to go when just specifying one. No, associations are not generated. Whatever, just open the files and throw it in, where's the problem?

Comment: many thanks mate . So finally I hope rails generate additional_detail user_id:integer name:string content:text visible:boolean this will generate the model and I then just need to add in User model, has_many :additional_details. And I am done ryt ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem too; I think an hash-like table could be the solution, something like this:

```
rails generate model UserDetails label:string value:string \
  visible:boolean user:references
```

in which you put records like this:

```
user.details.create(:label => 'Dog name', :value => 'Fuffy' :visible => false)
```